# SalesForce SOAP API create a Contact

Tags: php, salesforce

I'm using https://github.com/phpforce/soap-client to work with the SOAP api and so far i can login and it seems as if i can create a contact (in that i dont get any errors whereas for a while i was getting exceptions for random stuff)

But, when using create() with the right info i get null returned and finding it difficult to debug. it should be doing something ....

Mainly i'm asking: can i push directly to create a contact? Or do i have to sandbox it first? Someone might know this at least.

Comment: the reponse says that saving was true, but i dont see the contact in my account so no idea what's happening. is it staged somewhere?

Comment: how are you looking for your contact, take the ID from the returned value, and stick in the brower url,.g. https://xxx.salesforce.com/<id>